# Wordpress - Exclude a category from appearing in menu or sidebar widgets

Tags: wordpress, categories, sidebar

Is there a simple solution (e.g a plugin) for excluding categories appearing in  a menu or sidebar?
I created a category of posts called "videos" which display youtube videos (naturally!!) but then i realized they were displaying in my "recent posts" sidebar, and i was looking for a simple way to exclude them

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I found [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/excluding-category-from-widget) code in WordPress forum which seems to do exactly what you need:

```
<?php
  function exclude_widget_categories($args)
  {
    $exclude = "3,6,18"; // The IDs of the excluding categories
    $args["exclude"] = $exclude;
    return $args;
  }
  add_filter("widget_categories_args","exclude_widget_categories");
?>
```

Put the code in functions.php of your theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple plugin widget instead where you can specify certain categories

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-recent-posts-widget

Comment: Thank you for your answer Robert, I am however looking for something that will work with an existing widget, As i had my eyes on another plugin and was wondering if excluding categories can be set with any pluin

Comment: Excluding categories is an option based on the design of the plugin.  Depending on what you had in mind if it was not designed that way you would need to edit the code in order to have it exclude based on categories.