# excluding categories from the category widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to exclude certain categories from the standard category widget in wp

In my functions I put this which I got from the codex but it's not working at all. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408227/wordpress-exclude-a-category-from-appearing-in-menu-or-sidebar-widgets)

Am I missing something

```
function exclude_widget_categories($args)
  {
    $exclude_arr = array( 3,5,17);
    if( isset( $cat_args['exclude'] ) && !empty( $cat_args['exclude'] ) )
        $exclude_arr = array_unique( array_merge( explode( ',', $cat_args['exclude'] ), $exclude_arr ) );
    $cat_args['exclude'] = implode( ',', $exclude_arr );
    return $cat_args    
  }
  add_filter('widget_categories_args','exclude_widget_categories', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is wrong, in the parameter is `$args`, but you're using `$cat_args` in function.

Should be:

```
function exclude_widget_categories( $cat_args ) {}
```

Comment: thanks - did that, made that change - still doesn't work

Comment: On the off chance I changed the mode of display for the categories from dropdown to list. Now its working.... put it back onto dropdown and its stops working. So, that's now officially weird. I can live with a list (though would prefer dropdown)

Comment: It makes sense, cause the hook `widget_categories_args` acts at `wp_list_categories()`

Comment: Try using the hook `widget_categories_dropdown_args` to act at dropdown .