# Wordpress - Hide category from sidebar

Tags: wordpress

I'm using "[Recently Viewed Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/recently-viewed-posts/)" widget for my website showing what visitor recently visited post/page, by default the widget show all category posts from the list, I need a way to hide a post category from from the widget.

Anyways here's my code.

```
<?php
function exclude_widget_categories($args){
$exclude = “3,6,18”; // The IDs of the excluding categories
$args[“exclude”] = $exclude;
return $args;
}
add_filter(“widget_categories_args”,”exclude_widget_categories”);
?>
```

I Took that from here: [Wordpress - Exclude a category from appearing in menu or sidebar widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408227/wordpress-exclude-a-category-from-appearing-in-menu-or-sidebar-widgets)

Comment: So is the code not working for you? The quotes in the code you posted are not correct. `" "`. Try deleting them and typing them again while editing your file in a text editor like Notepad++. Also the code goes in functions.php so you will not include the `php` tags.

Comment: still no luck, I have also tried using `$exclude = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26";` and none of my category posts removed.

Comment: still can't figured out how to do it, or can you please suggest a better plugins. thanks